# onprem machines to Azure Active Directory so we can access ActiveDirectoryMSI authentication as well as IMDS SERVER

Tags: java, sql, azure, mssql-jdbc, adal4j

We want to use AzureSqlServer with ActiveDirectoryMSI authentication as well as token-based authentication and
We are able to execute successfully from VM created in Azure network and added as a member of the Azure AD group.
For that, we have created Contained user by following the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql

And added the VM as part of AzureActiveDirectory
by following this link

[com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: MSI Token failure: Failed to acquire token from MSI Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875054/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-msi-token-failure-failed-to-ac)

And we are able to access the SQL data without providing username and password using both IMDS server and able to retrieve the token using
http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fdatabase.windows.net%2F

and

ActiveDirectorMSI
URIString jdbc:sqlserver://azuresqlserverNAME:1433;databaseName=DatabaseNAME;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi;
.

But when it comes to access from Onprem Windows/Linux/Mac machine we are not able to access Azure SQL server

Can someone please suggest to me in terms of on-prem what needs to be done so we can access AzureSqlServer with ActiveDirectoryMSI Authentication as well as token-based authentication?

Comment: As far as I knew, we cannot use Azure MSI on-premise. According to the situation, I suggest you use `EnvironmentCredential` to get token and connect Azure SQL:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-java-preview

Comment: Hi, @JimXu thanks for replying can you please tell me what is the prereq to getting that token from the On-prem machine.

I mean on-prem machine should be the part of Azure Active Directory to access the azure resource and both should be under the same network. 

If you can help with that would be a great aid for me.

Comment: What do you mean `on-prem machine should be the part of Azure Active Directory`?

Comment: @JimXu on-prem means out-side of the Azure network Like your personal operating system have added it as part of Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to connect Azure SQL on-premise machine, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a service principal

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n 'name' --skip-assignment
```

2. [Add the service principal as Azure SQL database contained user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities).
3. Set environment variable. Please set the following variable as the environment variable

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID: ID of the service principal's tenant. Also called its 'directory' ID.

AZURE_CLIENT_ID: the service principal's client ID

AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: one of the service principal's client secrets
```

4. SDK

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.2.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

5. code

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
    {
     AccessToken token= GetAccessToken();
     SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();

        ds.setServerName("<>.database.windows.net"); // Replace with your server name.
        ds.setDatabaseName("demo"); // Replace with your database name.
        ds.setAccessToken(token.getToken());

        try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection(); 
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUSER_SNAME()")) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("You have successfully logged on as: " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    public static  AccessToken GetAccessToken() {
        DefaultAzureCredential creds = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
                .build();
        TokenRequestContext request = new TokenRequestContext();
        System.out.println("444");
        request.addScopes("https://database.windows.net//.default");
        String token;
        AccessToken accesstoken=creds.getToken(request).block();
        
        return accesstoken;
                
                
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  @jimxu it worked for me.

Can we use multiple on-prem machines with the same environment variable provided in a different machine simultaneously?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: Thanks, @JimXu for being a life saviour.

Comment: Hi @jimxu when I integrated with my application I'm kept getting the below error

reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported curveId: 29

Here is the GitHub post
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/12799

Could you please look into this and help me out.

Comment: @AjayKumarJaiswal please try to upgrade sdk version to `com.azure:azure-identity:1.1.0-beta.4` and add `executorService()`.

Comment: Hi @jimxu

Even after using executerservice i'm getting error

com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset


What is causing these errors still unknown for me?

Can we get access token using Postman so I can write my custom code using httpclient and set it in datasource.

Comment: @AjayKumarJaiswal Yes, you can do that

Comment: Hi @JimXu  i followed this and able to get the token and login in AzureSqlServer
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenent_ID}}}/oauth2/token");
  List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "client_ID"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "client_secret"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resource", "https://database.windows.net"));

Comment: I followed this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-azure-service-principal-and-get-aad-auth-token

But the problem is token get's expired, I'm not finding any way to get the refresh token.
Now I'm stuck with getting refresh token,
Can you suggest me how do I achieve this case.